# A colorpicker located inside a colormenu doesn't update though the UI

Tags: extjs

I have put an `Ext.picker.Color` inside an `Ext.menu.ColorPicker` that is inside an element that is inside a tbar...

```
{
    text: 'Choose a color',
    menu:{
        xtype: 'colormenu',//Ext.menu.ColorPicker
        picker:{
            xtype: 'colorpicker'//Ext.picker.Color
        }   
    }
}
```

A can set a color to it programmatically through this line:

`this.down('colorpicker').value='FF0000';`

but when I change the color through the UI the value doesn't change. Therefore if I execute this line

```
var newColor=this.down('colorpicker').getValue();
```

After selecting a new color I still get 'FF0000', even if I have clicked on the blue box (it should be '0000FF')

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.picker.Color.html#event-select)

Get the value inside colorpicker's select event like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'colorpicker'
    listeners: {
        select: function (colorpicker, color) {
                // color comes as a variable
        }
}
```